# Data import not processing in CartoDB?

Tags: carto

We've been trying for a while to get the CartoDB tech stack working and we've made progress but getting stuck when trying to import data via the API. The logs show the POST working fine and we're getting this in the DB:

```
data_source            | /usr/local/src/cartodb/public/uploads/b24076067e8d1bd6cfd1/twitters.csv
data_type              | file
table_name             | 
state                  | pending
success                | f
logger                 | 3525c925-f869-4349-bfd7-46447fea9345
updated_at             | 2015-04-07 04:21:51.628807+00
created_at             | 2015-04-07 04:21:51.62864+00
error_code             | 
queue_id               | 
tables_created_count   | 
table_names            | 
append                 | f
migrate_table          | 
table_copy             | 
from_query             | 
synchronization_id     | 
id                     | f03efe7d-1ce9-403b-b6f6-7da6147bb1a2
user_id                | f81a3066-7809-4bf7-a201-aebc948603da
table_id               | 
service_name           | public_url
service_item_id        | 
stats                  | {}
type_guessing          | t
quoted_fields_guessing | t
content_guessing       | f
server                 | 
host                   | 
upload_host            | ip-10-37-199-244
resque_ppid            |
```

But we're unclear what's supposed to happen next. The dashboard is showing a "Creating table" popup, seemingly based on the "pending" status, but nothing actually seems to be happening to import the data. I've found some code that seems related to kicking off import jobs (through resque?) but I'm having trouble making sense of it.

Any suggestions where to look, or what might be falling through the cracks?

Side note: it looks like the code eventually changes the status to "failed" after 60+ minutes of sitting in pending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you don't have the Rake that runs the import processing job:
 `VVERBOSE=true QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work`

Based on the "pending" status (`state` field in the DB row), and guessing that you're doing a normal upload and haven't configured Amazon S3 buckets to temporally store uploads there (see [this API Imports Controller](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/master/app/controllers/api/json/imports_controller.rb#L68) code for how it sets `pending` or `enqueued` state).

Hope this solves the issue!

Comment: That was the missing piece, thanks. Just no idea why that requirement wasn't accounted for in the provided start_stack/stop_stack scripts.